# PHP error: libphp5.so: undefined symbol: _estrndup

Tags: php, c, apache, makefile, configure

I compile Apache-MySQL-PHP by hand to build a custom install using the configure options from below. When I start apache it fails to start and adds the below error in the error_log.
* Apache 2
* Mysql 5.0
* PHP 5.1
* CentOS Linux 5.4
* GCC compiler

#### the error in apache log

httpd: Syntax error on line 54 of /opt/clamp/etc/httpd.conf: Cannot load /opt/clamp/modules/libphp5.so into server: /opt/clamp/modules/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: _estrndup

#### the ./configure options

APACHE
 ./configure \
 --prefix=/opt/clamp \
 --sysconfdir=/opt/clamp/etc \
 --enable-auth-dbm \
 --enable-cern-meta \
 --enable-auth-digest \
 --enable-charset-lite \
 --enable-deflate \
 --enable-expires \
 --enable-cache \
 --enable-disk-cache \
 --enable-file-cache \
 --enable-headers \
 --enable-info \
 --enable-mime-magic \
 --enable-proxy \
 --enable-proxy-ajp \
 --enable-proxy-balancer \
 --enable-proxy-connect \
 --enable-proxy-ftp \
 --enable-proxy-http \
 --enable-rewrite \
 --enable-so \
 --enable-ssl

MYSQL
 ./configure \
 --prefix=/opt/clamp \
 --sysconfdir=/opt/clamp/etc \
 --libexecdir=/opt/clamp/sbin \
 --localstatedir=/opt/clamp/var \
 --with-unix-socket-path=/opt/clamp/tmp/mysql.sock \
 --enable-thread-safe

PHP
 ./configure \
 --prefix=/opt/clamp \
 --sysconfdir=/opt/clamp/etc \
 --with-apxs2=/opt/clamp/bin/apxs \
 --with-config-file-path=/opt/clamp/etc/php.conf \
 --with-mysql=/opt/clamp \
 --with-mysqli=/opt/clamp/bin/mysql_config \
 --enable-force-cgi-redirect \
 --disable-cgi \
 --with-zlib \
 --with-gettext \
 --with-gdbm \
 --with-ldap \
 --with-ldap-sasl \
 --enable-zip \
 --with-bz2 \
 --with-gd \
 --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
 --with-png-dir=/usr

Comment: note that the error apeared after i tryed adding gd support via `--enable-zip --with-bz2 --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-png-dir=/usr`

Comment: First of all : precise which platform (Linux, ok, but which distro), which compiler. And don't forget this very useful command line which search through all the C files (subdir included) which ones contains the word: "find . | grep \.h$ | xargs grep [the word you're looking for] ". Finally, google is your friend: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/php-and-apache-392587/

Comment: Platform is CentOS Linux, gcc compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I wasn't building PHP's GD library right, building PHP with the following options worked (no more error):

cd php-5.2.13/
./configure \
--prefix=/opt/clamp \
--sysconfdir=/opt/clamp/etc \
--with-apxs2=/opt/clamp/bin/apxs \
--with-config-file-path=/opt/clamp/etc/php.conf \
--disable-debug \
--with-pic \
--disable-rpath \
--without-pear \
--with-bz2 \
--with-curl \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr \
--with-png-dir=/usr \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--without-gdbm \
--with-gettext \
--with-gmp \
--with-iconv \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
--with-openssl \
--with-pspell \
--with-zlib \
--with-layout=GNU \
--enable-exif \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-magic-quotes \
--enable-sockets \
--enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-sysvmsg \
--enable-wddx \
--with-kerberos \
--enable-ucd-snmp-hack \
--enable-shmop \
--enable-calendar \
--without-sqlite \
--enable-force-cgi-redirect \
--enable-pcntl \
--with-imap --with-imap-ssl \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-mbregex \
--with-ncurses \
--with-gd \
--enable-bcmath \
--with-xmlrpc \
--with-ldap --with-ldap-sasl \
--with-mysql=/opt/clamp \
--with-mysqli=/opt/clamp/bin/mysql_config \
--enable-dom \
--with-pgsql \
--enable-soap \
--enable-xmlreader --enable-xmlwriter \
--enable-fastcgi 
make
make install

Answer (score 0):

if you are not gonna read all the error logs, you can try:

```
char *
estrndup(const char *s, size_t len)
{
    char *d = strndup(s, len);
    //if (d == NULL)
    //  (*efunc)(1, "Cannot copy string");
    return d;
}
```

Comment: what other log i should read?

Comment: i meant, that if you are not gonna read any error logs, then you may try provided snippet

Answer (score -1):

It means you haven't got your php build correctly, probably because you have make it several times, like I did, and only the last time you got through. Between these times of builds you have installed some supporting packages along the way, which you forgot to do at the beginning. Therefore you without make clean you end up with something that is not clean. 
And Apache is just too picky to do it. So the best try is to run 'make clean' again and rebuild php to see what really happend.